# Error "org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report." when trying to run report via tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, birt

I have created a BIRT report that uses an informix database and an excel-file as datasources. On my local PC it runs just fine. But when I try to run it via tomcat on my server I get the error

org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.

and the following stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1115)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
  at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
  at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
  at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:514)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:582)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:212)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:682)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:932)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2375)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)
  53 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.poi.POIXMLRelation"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:881)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:881)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable(XSSFReader.java:77)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.util.XlsxFileReader.processSheet(XlsxFileReader.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.util.ExcelFileReader.initialise(ExcelFileReader.java:159)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.util.ExcelFileReader.readLine(ExcelFileReader.java:104)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.util.ExcelFileSource.getColumnCount(ExcelFileSource.java:237)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.ExcelFileQuery.prepareMetaData(ExcelFileQuery.java:185)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel.impl.ExcelFileQuery.getMetaData(ExcelFileQuery.java:632)
  at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doGetMetaData(OdaQuery.java:423)
  at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.getMetaData(OdaQuery.java:390)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:407)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getProjectedColumns(PreparedStatement.java:377)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.declareCustomColumn(PreparedStatement.java:1223)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.addCustomFields(DataSourceQuery.java:686)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepareColumns(DataSourceQuery.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepare(DataSourceQuery.java:347)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.prepareOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:621)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:349)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:179)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:159)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.populatePreparedQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:557)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.populatePreparedQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:507)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.access$2(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:493)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery$JointDataSetQueryExecutor.createOdiQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:589)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:333)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:159)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.populatePreparedQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:557)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.populatePreparedQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:495)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.access$2(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:493)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedJointDataSourceQuery$JointDataSetQueryExecutor.createOdiQuery(PreparedJointDataSourceQuery.java:589)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:333)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
  at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:651)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:285)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1947)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
  at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
  55 more
```

I have created reports before that use the same datasources and they work just fine and are deployed via the tomcat without problems.

Can someone please help me? I cannot figure out what I have done wrong in this report.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.poi.POIXMLRelation"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package` is the root cause.